# Displaying the saved name for self-phone number in WhatsApp

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I have my own WhatsApp account's number stored as a contact in my mobile.

Theoretically, WhatsApp should detect my own number from the contacts list and show the name of the contact as set in the list of chats if I send myself a message.

The following screenshot shows the chat thread with my own phone number even though it's already saved in the contact.

[image]

Is it possible to display the name from the saved contact instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it should. However, WhatsApp doesn't allow that. So, whilst you can still *somehow* start a chat with your own number and send messages, there's no way to make WhatsApp see it as a contact and show it with a name. I have tried saving it in different ways to no avail.
I often use the self chat to save important messages and to take notes without having to send the message to a random contact. And for that I just type in my number to quickly get it there.